# Can't catch exception from fs.createWriteStream()

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch, electron

In the main process of my Electron app, I'm trying to handle an exception thrown when creating a file that already exists. However, my catch clause is never entered, and the exception is spammed to the user. What am I doing wrong?

```
let file;
try {
    // this line throws *uncaught* exception if file exists - why???
    file = fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/existing/file', {flags: 'wx'}); 
}
catch (err) {
    // never gets here - why???
}
```

Comment: `createWriteStream` does not throw an exception, it passes an error to its *asynchronous callback*.

Comment: Unlike some of the other `fs` methods, `createWriteStream` doesn't accept a callback.

Comment: Yeah, right, it emits `error` events that you need to handle with a callback (and apparently, if there are no handlers registered, it throws a global exception asynchronously).

Comment: The global async exception was the bit that was confusing me. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct way to handle this case is by listening to the `error` event:

```
const file = fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/existing/file', {flags: 'wx'});
file.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    file.end();
});
```

Comment: Is file.end() required if autoClose is defaulted (true)?

Comment: the error occurs before the file const exists, so this can't catch the error on stream creation

Answer (score 1):

What I've found is:
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2479

I tried to replicate with pure Node.js, and it catches errors with `process.on('uncaughtException', callback)`

```
let desiredPath = '/mnt/c/hello.txt';
let fs = require('fs');

process.on('uncaughtException', function (error) {
    console.log('hello1');
});

try {
  fs.createWriteStream(desiredPath, {
    flags: 'wx',
  });
}
catch (err) {
  console.log('hello');
}

//Output is: 'hello1'
```

I tried it with Ubuntu shell on Windows 10, in my case I don't have permissions to read that file and `process.on('uncaughtException', callback)` catches it correctly.